# Equivalents definition of linear convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Suppose that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$.

I want to prove that these definitions are equivalent:

**a)** We say that $\{x_n\}$ converges linearly to $0$, if there exists a number $q \in (0, 1) $ and a constant $C>0$ such that $x_n \leq C q^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

**b)** We say that  $\{x_n\}$ converges linearly to $0$, if there exists a number $q \in (0, 1) $ and  constants $C>0$, $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \leq C q^n$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Clearly $a)\Rightarrow b)$.

Does $b)\Rightarrow a)$ ? How could I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $x_n \leq Cq^n \leq Dq^n$ for all $n\geq n_0$, if $C\leq D$. With this,
$$D = \max\left\{C,\frac{x_1}{q^1},\dots, \frac{x_{n_0}}{q^{n_0}}\right\}$$
is a suitable constant for a).